# Vertical and Horizontal Bars - An Instructionless Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

[image]

> **Study the 2 examples given on the left and solve the puzzle on the right!**
>   The solution for each puzzle can be uniquely determined.

Comment: Addendum: on the second example, the second row should be 2 instead of ?

Comment: Should the third row in the second example should be 3 rather than 2 1?

Comment: @Deusovi 2 1 is fine :)

Comment: Addendum 2: the second number on fifth column should be 2 instead of ? *(Damn.. I should have playtested this first :( I'm so embarassed)*

Comment: Why the heck is there a VTC on this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This appears to be similar to a [Nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram) puzzle, except each cell is filled in as a vertical or horizontal bar instead of black, and a horizontal or vertical bar instead of a blank, if you are looking at a column or row respectively But it's not that simple, as @Deusovi points out, there is a inconsistency. If, however we change the rules slightly more to allow adjacency of two numbers,

then...

> This solution follows:
>
>  [image]

Comment: There was an update - the fifth column should have a 2 instead of a question mark.

Comment: oh, I accidentally undid that change

Comment: @Deusovi, there we go, I've fixed it, there is indeed only one solution.

Comment: That's correct! :D I will accept the answer after a while :) ~ Indeed it's similar with ROT13(ababtenz) but it's actually different. I *was* planning to create a mobile game with this puzzle where each number represents ROT13(pngf), precisely ROT13(gur yratgu bs pngf). The goal is to ROT13(cynpr gur pngf ba gur obneq fhpu gung gurl ner abg bireynccvat). The catch is that ROT13(pngf ba rnpu ebjf pna bayl or qenttrq ubevmbagnyyl juvyr ba rnpu pbyhza iregvpnyyl). Hope this clears up how the puzzle works, :3